# How is the cpu clock connected to other components

Tags: clock, cpu-architecture

How is the cpu clock connected to other components. and what do people mean by saying all operations start at a clock tick.

Comment: Do you mind linking to this 'how does the cpu clock work' you reffer to?

Comment: @FalcoGer my bad they are quora posts i will remove this line

Answer (score 2):

The CPU Clock drives the CPU. Internally there is a bus system, basically a bundle of electrical connections. Someone, and only one, may put their data on it. For example a register output, or the ALU result (Well, they don't want to, they're told to do so by the control unit, which makes sure only one entity may access the bus in write mode).
This operation is unsafe as logic may fluctuate the electrical signal several times while it moves through the logic gates until it stabilizes, or some signals will come earlier than others. This depends on capacitive and inductive effects and such, delaying the signals.
Because of this, no one will read the data off the bus until the clock triggers. The clock pulse indicates that enough time has passed that the signals ought to be safe and it is assumed the signal on the bus is stable.
This is done by simply using an and-gate or an edge detector with the clock signal on the devices that want to read from the bus.

Example:

```
Data-Bus ----/8----- [   ]
Data-In  ----------- [ R ]
Data-Out ----------- [ E ]
Clk      ----------- [ G ]

' Data-Out may be asyncronous like this, though not recommended, or on falling/low clock pulse, or the Data-Out signal is clock synced:
Data-Bus[0] = Data-Out AND Data[0]
Data-Bus[1] = Data-Out AND Data[1]
Data-Bus[2] = Data-Out AND Data[2]
[...]
' Data-In will almost always be clock synced
If (Data-In AND Raising-Clk-Edge)
{
    Data[0] = Data-Bus[0]
    Data[1] = Data-Bus[1]
    [...]
}
```

This is of course highly dependant on your actual hardware. For example Read-Enable, Write-Enable and Output-Enable can be active low, etc.

There is a [great youtube series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyznrdDSSGM&list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU) of a guy actually building a CPU on a breadboard. While of course this is overly simplified in regards what a modern cpu does, it helps to understand the basics.

The cpu clock itself is usually not directly connected to other hardware, and instead the cpu generates the trigger pulses that tell others it's safe to read/write from/to the bus now.

Each instruction may be made up from several microinstructions. For example:
`LDA #5`, Load 5 into the A-Register

```
' Fetch
Put IP on Address bus, Enable memory out => Opcode for LDA-Immediate is now on Data-Bus
Write-Enable Instruction Register, Increment IP
' Decode with combinatorial logic
' CU realizes it needs another word from memory (the value) and it needs to go to the A-Register
' Execute
Put IP on Address bus, Enable memory out => #5 now on data-bus
Increment IP, Write-Enable A-Register => #5 now in A-Register
' Done
```

This is done by the cpu clock. the system clock has little to do with that.

Comment: Is the cpu clock = the bus clock i am quite fimiliar with the bus clock and why it's used but i didn't think they are the same the thing (like when a product gets advertised (intel i7  2.6ghz clock speed) are we talking about the same clock (thanks sorry for confusion) )

Comment: @mohamedazaiez the cpu clock will advance each microinstruction internally in the cpu. each assembly instruction may be made up from several microinstructions. for example `LDA  #5` (load the value 5 into A-Register) may be made up from `Put IP register on address bus`, `Put data bus value to instruction register`, `decode instruction` (realize it is load immediate and you need another byte), `put 5 on databus and register a in input mode`. using such (inefficient) microcode you'd need more than 1 cycle for this instruction. the systembus is triggered by the cpu, not the cpu clock itself.